# Website ip address printer not working in python

Tags: python, sockets

my code is here

```
ip=int(input("What website do u need the ip address from?"))
ipad=socket.gethostbyname(ip)
print("Thats websites ip is",ipad)
wait=input("Press enter to exit")
os.system('cls')
```

Then this returns an error
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'www.google.com'`

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
ip=int(input("What website do u need the ip address from?"))
```

So for some reason you are trying to convert your input to an integer and then assign that to a variable called "ip". If you type an integer then your error will go away - of course that's no use if you want people to type webite hostnames.

Whenever you get an error like this, stop, read the error message carefully and precisely and examine the code you have. Not the code you *think* you wrote, but what is on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You cant cast string  '`www.google.com'` to `int`

Moreover, `socket.gethostbyname(hostname)` translates a host name to IPv4 address format, so its input is not `int`, but `string`.